# C# MVC ADFS Authentication

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, adfs

I have a C# MVC application which requires ADFS authentication. ADFS was not considered at the initial stage of the development until completion of the application. Any ideas on how to make the application aware of ADFS? I have configured ADFS with the right claims, the challenge is making the application aware. Any idea is appreciated. I am using ADFS 2.0. It is On-Premise ADFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Building My First Claims-Aware ASP.NET Web Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/building-my-first-claims-aware-aspnet-web-app)
- [Deploying Active Directory Federation Services in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-azure-adfs)
- [Use the On-Premises Organizational Authentication Option (ADFS) With ASP.NET
  in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/)
- [Using ADFS with Azure for Single Sign-On
  in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1158/using-adfs-azure-single-signon-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: Thanks Azzhag, but this will only apply if I were to start afresh.

Comment: Then you'll need to provide details about the exact difficulties you're encountering; it's a vast subject with no easy answers, I think. 'Making an application aware' could mean something as easy as configuring WIF like in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-build-claims-aware-aspnet-mvc-web-app-using-wif

Answer (score 1):

Making the application "ADFS aware" requires that the application uses one of the supported protocols i.e. WS-Fed, SAML or OpenID Connect.

Adding WIF (WS-Fed) is a good option.